# Change mapped source path for assembly in VS Debugger

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

When trying to debug into asp.net identity source, I cloned the source from codeplex and when stepping into the code mapped the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` to my `/code/aspnetidentity` directory.

I think I made a mistake however in cloning that repo - it seems incomplete. I found a different one on github and have it at `/code/Identity`. However, I have no idea where the mapping from assembly to source code directory is stored so that I can change it.

Where is it?

Comment: Could you share us the link where you download the source for this project? In addition, what is the version number of the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework? If it was installed through the Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/, my understanding is that the assembly directory would be related to how this package was created. For example, we could use the NuGet Package Explorer  to really visit the composition and structure of it.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I think you misunderstand. When you have Just My Code disabled and framework source stepping on, when you attempt to user the debugger to step into 3rd party code, the debugger will ask if you have the source so that it can walk it (extensions like dotnetpeek can additionally decompile). You give it a directory, and it will attempt to point to match up the running code with lines in source files so you can step through. What happens if I gave it the wrong directory? How do I change it? I simply do not know where to find that option.

Comment: I think we need to know that how VS find source files firstly before we want to know that whether it really impacts your debugging with a different directory. see"Find source files" here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Ok...I think thats closer, though the Debug Source Files window is empty....not sure if this re-set or if its stored empty.

Comment: Could you find the source file using certain tool now? What about this issue?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT nope it still isn't showing up. Though now I have an additional issue. asp.net identity didn't tag their releases so it would seem nobody knows exactly which versions correspond to what's in nuget. HKao gave me a commit id but I'm still getting obvious mismatches in certain files.

Comment: PDB files contain absolute paths to the source code files, so maybe it is a path if you really want to find more information for the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure that why it was empty, but the symbol file contains the original location of the source files, so one idea is that you could use certain tool like Windbg or others to really find and read the source file:

[How do I change the locations of source files in a symbols file (pdb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952/how-do-i-change-the-locations-of-source-files-in-a-symbols-file-pdb)

[Get the original source code location for an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750388/get-the-original-source-code-location-for-an-assembly)